# Simplifying Multiple Integral Expressions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Suppose i have the following multiple integral expressions...

\begin{align}
I_1 = {} & \int_x^{x+1}x_1^n\,dx_1 \\[10pt]
I_2 = {} & \int_x^{x+1}\int_0^{x_1}x_2^n\,dx_2\,dx_1-\int_0^xx_1^n\,dx_1 \\[10pt]
I_3 = {} & \int_x^{x+1}\int_0^{x_1}\int_0^{x_2}x_3^n\,dx_3\,dx_2\,dx_1-\int_0^x \int_0^{x_1} x_2^n\,dx_2\,dx_1-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^xx_1^n\,dx_1 \\[10pt]
I_4 = {} & \int_x^{x+1}\int_0^{x_1} \int_0^{x_2} \int_0^{x_3} x_4^n \,dx_4 \,dx_3 \,dx_2\,dx_1 -\int_0^x\int_0^{x_1} \int_0^{x_2} x_3^n \,dx_3\,dx_2\,dx_1 \\[5pt]
& {} -\frac{1}{2} \int_0^x \int_0^{x_1} x_2^n \, dx_2 \, dx_1-\frac{1}{6}\int_0^xx_1^n \, dx_1
\end{align}

Is there a way to generalize these expressions for higher and higher cases of $I_k$?  There is clearly a pattern, but writing this out for $I_k, k>4$ seems daunting and I wasn't sure if there was an agreed upon way to 'compactify' these types of expressions.

Comment: Have you tried to integrate the expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k \in \mathbb{N}$,$$I_k=n! \left(\frac{(x+1)^{n-k}}{(n+k)!}-\sum_{a=1}^{k}\frac{x^{n+a}}{(n+a)!(k-a)!}\right)$$

Comment: exactly, no idea where ops problems originate (+1)

Comment: How did you get this ?

Comment: The problem originates from operators.  If we let $t^kx^n=D_x^k[x^n]$, then a formal power series can be an operator and for function like $\frac{e^t-1}{t}, \frac{e^t-1-t}{t^2}, $ etc, the results are given above in terms of integrals.  I was hoping to end up with simpler integral expressions instead of the discrete summations above, but I now have some information i need for other work.  Thank you.